# Probability mass function of product of 2 dice

Tags: probability, dice

I'm trying to obtain the PMF of the product of two dice. I've made the following table:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline product & occurrence \\ \hline 1 & 1 \\ \hline 2 & 2 \\ \hline 3 & 2 \\ \hline 4 & 3 \\ \hline 5 & 2 \\ \hline 6 & 4 \\ \hline 8 & 2 \\ \hline 9 & 1 \\ \hline 10 & 2 \\ \hline 12 & 4 \\ \hline 15 & 2 \\ \hline 16 & 1 \\ \hline 18 & 2 \\ \hline 20 & 2 \\ \hline 24 & 2 \\ \hline 25 & 1 \\ \hline 30 & 2 \\ \hline 36 & 1 \\ \hline  \end{array}

What could work as a possible PMF from this data? Can an expression for the product of two dice be given like the one for the sum: $p_k = \frac{6-|k-7|}{36}$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a discrete pdf or a continuous approximation?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean PMF since this is discrete. Since you have 36 options, diving your "occurrence" by 36 to get the probability of getting that product (for example, probability of getting a 20 is 2/36).

Comment: Yes, a PMF, I'll edit that. Thanks.